# How to upload / import a mysql phpmydadmin database of more than 2MB

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

With the default settings, `phpmyadmin` does not allow me to upload a database of more than `2mb`. How to `upload or import` in a `mysql phpmydadmin` database of more than `2MB`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a couple of ways.

1) Split your SQL file into multiple 2MB chunks

### OR

2) update your php.ini file with the following (only works on dedicated/local servers - any server you have root on or ones that allow php.ini to be override)

```
Find:
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 8M

Change to: ( or any size you want but it will depend on your server resources )
post_max_size = 35M
upload_max_filesize = 35M
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 1000M
```

3) If you do have root run a command line

```
mysql -u username -p -D database_name < file
```

Comment: I have change xampp/php/php.ini files as you told but I still have the same problem , what can i do ?

Comment: what is the location of php.ini?

Answer (score 2):

Archive that dump in a `.tar.gz` file and upload that file

Comment: I am not so sure about it - I overcame that issue in several cases by simply loading an archived DB dump

Comment: it takes into effect the upload default and the max execution time of the php/apache server. Which the default max execution time is 30 secs (pure just setup and unmodified apache/php server)

Answer (score 0):

The 2 Mb limit on file uploads is a default setting in PHP so you'll need to increase it in your `php.ini` file.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php  Note that more than one setting may need to be increased.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/.

This splits the dump files into small chunks and uploads them automatically.